# Can you access the framebuffer from a python GUI library?

Tags: python

Is there a way to access the framebuffer of a GUI library like pyside2 or tkinter? I want to send the frames rendered by these libraries to a virtual video device on Ubuntu.

I want to use pyvirtualcam to send frames to a virtual camera created using v4l2loopback as shown [here](https://github.com/letmaik/pyvirtualcam#linux-v4l2loopback). Then I'd like to use [pylivestream](https://pypi.org/project/pylivestream/) to stream that virtual camera to YouTube. So, it'd be great if there was a way I could draw the GUI to a frame and send it to the virtual camera, instead of using screen capture.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do better please? What virtual video device? Send *how* and to what purpose? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've updated the question. Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: I don't know about pyside, but you can't do it from tkinter.